# Loading javascript with turbolink plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I know there is `jQuery-turbolinks`. But is there anyway to use jQuery and JS with turbolink.

https://github.com/rails/turbolinks

With `Turbolinks` pages will change without a full reload, so you can't rely on `DOMContentLoaded` or `jQuery.ready()` to trigger your code. Instead Turbolinks fires events on document to provide hooks into the lifecycle of the page.

I had this piece of code, but this did not load on `navigating` to other url.

```
$(function() {
  return $('.status').hover(function(event) {
    return $(this).toggleClass("hover");
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way to use that function with *only* `turbolinks`?? Because it should work with *both* `turbolinks` and `jquery-turbolinks` after including `jquery.turbolinks` in your `application.js` file.

Comment: @Justin: If we don't use jQuery-turbolinks?.

Comment: check my answer, it should work

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following to run your javascript on both page:load and ready.

```
$(document).on('page:load ready', function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: What is this page:load ? Is it a jQuery thing or turbolinks?

Comment: It's a browser event provided by turbolinks, triggered when you navigate to a different page.

Answer (score 1):

Try it out ;)

```
var ready;
ready = function() {
  $(function() {
    return $('.status').hover(function(event) {
      return $(this).toggleClass("hover");
    });
  });
};
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Comment: What is this page:load ? Is it a jQuery thing or turbolinks?

Answer (score 0):

This doc showing how to: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
      // ... Your code here!
    })
```